# International Super Star Soccer 64 Main Theme Genre

Tags: identify-this-genre, videogame-soundtrack, genre-characteristics

Wich genre would you say that the [International Super Star Soccer 64's main theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siZZoTP8owE) is?

Also, what about the [training theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYO7SXfJe3E)?

Comment: Why is everybody these days fixated with pigeon-holing everything. It's music. If you like it, listen to it. If you don't... don't. Don't worry about what pigeon-hole everything fits in. It will end up with just one pigeon per hole at this rate.

Comment: Calm down, man. I'm actually not worried about pigeon-holing anything. I just want to listen something similar, and to be able to do that, I must know what should I go after, eh?

Comment: The genre you are looking for is videogame music.  That's all there is to it, unfortunately.  Most compilers will not get any more specific other than specifying that it is from the N64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's videogame music.  Specifically, it is videogame music for the N64, from Japan.  The music isn't part of any other genre as its sole purpose is to amuse and therefore takes several elements at whim.  The core of the music, the trope of music that grounds it is found in prior Mario music composed by Koji Kondo, Seiichi Tokunaga, and Kenta Nagata.